# What SharePoint 2013 Development can be done in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: development, visual-studio, 2013, office-365-develop-tool

It looks like the tools for developing SharePoint 2013 customizations are mostly in Visual Studio 2012 and "Napa for Office 365."

If you've tried developing solutions for SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2010, what has worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to [Hugh's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/49610/45159), almost anything you can do in VS 2010 for SP10 works in SP13 (event receivers, web parts, etc.), but nothing new, or not much of the new features work in VS2010 because much of them are new templates and data techniques such as the app model, remote event receivers, etc.

The App model requires the ability to do remote development which is built into VS 2012, but not 2010 and the SharePoint add on for VS is for 2012, not 2010.

By the way, it is Visual Studio 2012, not 2013, confusing, I know.

A positive push for VS 2012 is that remote development and deployment is allow, which matches Microsoft's push towards SharePoint online (office 365).

Comment: Everything I've read regarding remote development has been geared towards apps. Can we deploy/debug solutions remotely is the only way to debug/deploy through VS is if you're doing it on the server? I can't seem to get that figured out -- especially when "app" refers to _anything_ you can do to a SharePoint site.

Comment: From what I have seen, you can deploy anything remotely because you are allowed to log into remote servers from VS now. The server requirements for 2013 makes it harder to have it installed on individual developer VMs.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work for the most part, but I am not confident about things like workflows as I have had two not work now which work on 2010.

We are in the middle of upgrading visual studio now though, as a company we don't believe the risks of incompatibility outweigh the costs.

Comment: Thanks, Hugh. Workflow makes sense because the custom workflow model is different in 2013. Have you tried installing the App Model tools? I don't imagine those would work either.

Comment: Yes we tried during our review before our license was updated, this was the point where we stopped testing however, we can't risk being incompatible even by 1%.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do loads still with VS2010 in SharePoint 2013. We do exactly that for DocRead (no time to upgrade to 2012). Check my post on supporting [multiple versions of SharePoint from 1 VS Solution](http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/mark-jones/2013/01/06/multiple-versions-sharepoint-visual-studio).

I just made an update to this article as I forgot to compile against .Net 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the link to your great article, @Mark jones. In summary, would you say that everything you need to do for SharePoint 2013 Development is available in VS2010 then?

Answer (score 0):

Some relevant article you can find here: http://faisalrafique.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/whats-new-for-sharepoint-development-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer] for general guidelines.

Comment: I agree with Kit. If you update your question with a summary of the content relevant to Visual Studio 2010 I would give an up vote.