# Sharepoint 2013 / VisualStudio 2008

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

We have installed a Sharepoint fondation 2013 and we are working with a VisualStudio 2008.
Do you think it will be possible to develop some webparts with this configuration ?

Comment: You can but not everything and as it going to be pain http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49601/what-sharepoint-2013-development-can-be-done-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: What's wrong with moving to VS 2012?

Answer (score 2):

I think, it is not possible. Mainly because of the below reasons

1. VS 2008 lacks 2013 web part templates.
2. .NET version used in SP 2013

I am not sure, if we can have extensions for VS 2008 to develop for SP 2013.

Ideal Tool for SP 2013 is

> Visual Studio 2012

.

Comment: That's not right ! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49601/what-sharepoint-2013-development-can-be-done-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: That question refers to VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you: [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Tools: Visual Studio 2008 Extensions, Version 1.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=841)

Info about tools: Tools for developing custom SharePoint applications: Visual Studio project templates for Web Parts, site definitions, and list definitions; and a stand-alone utility program, the SharePoint Solution Generator.

I don't know if this will work on sharepoint 2013.